# Thymeleaf : an anchor in a th:action parameterized url makes my IDE (IntelliJ) and SonarLint mark it as an error (but it works)

Tags: url, thymeleaf, spring-thymeleaf

I use thymeleaf templates in a java17 / spring-boot project.

In a template I have this kind of form :

```html
<form th:if="${something}" th:action="@{/{firstThing}/{secondThing}/{thirdThing}(firstThing=${myDTO.firstThing}, secondThing=${myDTO.secondThing}, thirdThing=${myDTO.secondThing})}" method="post">
    <button type="submit" th:text="#{message.nextResultPage}"></button>
<form>
```

It works fine.
The th:action url actually returns the same template after some treatment.
I wanted to add an anchor so that when the user clicks on submit the displayed page sticks to the displayed result section.
I found that I could do that simply by adding a #something on thymeleaf's doc (section 6): [Thymeleaf Standard Url Syntax](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standardurlsyntax.html)

So my form now looks like that :

```html
<form th:if="${something}" th:action="@{/{firstThing}/{secondThing}/{thirdThing}#resultSection (firstThing=${myDTO.firstThing}, secondThing=${myDTO.secondThing}, thirdThing=${myDTO.secondThing})}" method="post">
    <button type="submit" th:text="#{message.nextResultPage}"></button>
<form>
```

The code does compile and the app is working as intended, but IntelliJ/SonarLint now tell me that there's an error located at the first comma :
'(', ')', '-', '.', ':', '=', ESCAPED_STRING_LITERAL, FLOATING_POINT_LITERAL, IDENTIFIER, INTEGER_LITERAL, STRING_IDENTIFIER, STRING_LITERAL or '{' expected, got ','

Is it just my IDE not recognizing it properly ? Or am I doing it wrong ?

Comment: If it works fine, then it is probably an IntelliJ issue. You can file a bug report at their [bug tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA). Might want to look at the [current open issues](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA?q=%23%7BLang.%20Thymeleaf%7D%20%23Open%20) to look if it was reported before.